# Is there a web query to get details from different sites

Tags: web

I was trying to develop an application, assume that it should list all public events/gatherings happening in Bangalore. For example all food festivals happening in bangalore in next 1 month or a mass movement like marathon race happening in next 4 months. But these details are available in different sites across the web.

Say, suppose I google for "Marathon races in bangalore". Events happening in Bangalore will be listed but the dteails will be in different websites. May be the Marathon organizers have websites of their own or they had put ads in some other websites. I want to get these details from the web. Is there something like a web query or any idea of how to get this data?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this for my town a long time ago, the short answer is no. The way I implemented it was to contact a bunch of local bars and ask them what their entertainment was for the weekend and then added it my self. After a while They got used to me and I added a feature to have them update the information.

If you find a site that displays events you could do a screen scrape for the information, but it is delicate, if they change the site your application breaks.